# Disabling style triggers created in xaml programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on a c# WPF project which I am using a style trigger to style the background colour of the each row based on one of the cell values.

Below is my style trigger.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highest Alarm Level}" Value="Critical">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highest Alarm Level}" Value="Medium">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highest Alarm Level}" Value="Warning">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highest Alarm Level}" Value="Info">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

What I need to be able to do, is under certain circumstances I don't want this style to be used, so what I am after, is if in the C# code a certain condition becomes to true, I want to disable all of the styling done above to not be used, i.e. all of the styling is turned off so the background colour of the rows are not set.

Comment: Create another `Style` without any triggers and switch between both in C# code.

Comment: Can you provide any links to examples and tutorials. Everything I found on the net doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Key to your custom `DataGridRow` `Style`

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="MyRowStyle">
    <!-- Define Triggers -->
</Style>
```

Then you just need to switch between default and custom styles.

If you set `Style` with `null`, that means the default `Style` will be applied

```
dataGrid.RowStyle = _boolCondition ? this.FindResource("MyRowStyle") as Style : null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works great. I was almost there but I was using dataGrid.style instead of dataGrid.RowStyle.